# liquibase : modify csv file and insert new records

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I load data into my database from a CSV file :

```
<loadUpdateData encoding="UTF-8"
    primaryKey="pk_id"
    file="config/liquibase/roles_admin.csv"
    separator=";"
    tableName="role_admin">
       <column name="libelle" type="STRING"/>
</loadUpdateData>
```

Is it possible to tell liquibase to insert new records if I add lines to my csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your changeSet and add `runAllways="true"` this way it will run always (even if there is no change).

Comment: If you do this, you will also get duplicate records. Liquibase does not currently have any logic to only insert data that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Using `runOnChange="true"` on your changeSet should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that i found to do that, is creating other csv file with the same columns like the original csv file and with the updated data, and create a new changeSet with loadUpdatedData inside and pointed to the new csv file.